# JavaScript code isn't working to show pictures while making dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to run a code,in which once an option is choosen through a drop down a picture should appear.Not sure but, only the first picture appears(It should be only because I have choosen it to start with) but thereafter nothing changes.Looks like my JS is not working at all.Sorry for posting a basic type,I am new to Javascript/HTML. Code is attached.

Tried keeping the javascript separate and calling it but didnt work.

```js
var pictureList = [
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5", ];
    $('#picDD').change(function () {
        var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
        $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
    });
```

```css
    img {
        width:400px;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
    <select id="picDD">
        <option value="1" selected>Picture 1</option>
        <option value="2">Picture 2</option>
        <option value="3">Picture 3</option>
        <option value="4">Picture 4</option>
        <option value="5">Picture 5</option>
    </select>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your code works perfectly fine. I think your forgot to include jquery libary

Comment: you do it like this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` paste this in the head tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jquery library to run your code. Add this script to your HTML code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you do not use this library, your select will not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since your base URL is same, you could also refactor the code as below without an array.

```js
$('#picDD').change(function() {
  $('img').attr("src",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" + $(this).val());
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
<select id="picDD">
  <option value="1" selected>Picture 1</option>
  <option value="2">Picture 2</option>
  <option value="3">Picture 3</option>
  <option value="4">Picture 4</option>
  <option value="5">Picture 5</option>
</select>
```